# Prestashop 1.6.x module custom endpoints

Tags: php, rest, module, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm developing module for PrestaShop, I've got my own views made in Vue.js (register, login, settings etc. pages) and I need custom endpoints in my module to comunicate with my views. I would like to avoid overriding core files in Presta. How to create some custom endpoints for my module?

Comment: By using [module controllers](https://belvg.com/blog/prestashop-1-7-mvc-part-2-creating-a-controller.html)?

Comment: @TheDrot
But using module controllers requires using url's like :
- http://example.com/admin/index.php?controller=ModuleName&action=doSomething
- doesn't it?

While I need routing (get/post) like:
http://example.com/admin/modulename/create
http://example.com/admin/modulename/login
http://example.com/admin/modulename/settings
etc...

Comment: Why would you need friendly URLs for admin links? Front end module controllers can have friendly URLs defined.

Comment: @TheDrot I have my own one-page views created in Vue.js, where routing is fixed to {base_url}/action. They contain pages to register/login on my own service, change settings etc. every view hits different url - like {base_url}/login, send post/get requests and wait for correct response. It's really important to me not to change core behavior of views, because they're multi-platform, used in couple of other platforms. (magento, shopify...)
I need {url}/action endpoint which my views will communicate with.

What would you suggest in this case? Is there a way to pass it without changing views?

Comment: Do you specifically need admin controllers? Maybe you could add htaccess directives in prestashop's admin folder to rewrite urls? I don't know exactly what your prestashop module endpoints do or what they need. Maybe you could use front controllers where URLs can be customized?

Comment: But can I use front controllers when my module is accessible strictly from admin panel? I would preffer not to change htaccess.

For example my {url}/login send post with login/pass, my module authenticate data in my website api, returns token in response which let you to pass to other views in my module.

{url}/register send post mail/pass, my module pass it to my website, creates account and retrieves integration data, which are saved in presta configuration, its required for webhooks and data export(customers/orders data) to work.

{url}/token GET checks if token is present in config

Comment: You can add custom checks to front controllers. If I understand correctly you can create a login endpoint on front controller and verify if an employee account exists in shop. Basically you recreate a shop backend login mechanic in a front controller and a successful login returns you some kind of token which you generate. Other front endpoints require this token to do whatever you want them to do. If these checks don't pass you probably want to return proper http response (I'm guessing you want to build REST endpoints). And to create friendly URLs use hook `moduleRoutes`.

Comment: If you get stuck in a specific step, write a new question. This question is too broad for any definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a PHP file in the module, for example, endpoint.php

```
<?php
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../config/config.inc.php');
```

After this, you will able to use any PrestaShop function and syntax like any other class file.

Comment: How would this actually help with my problem? I could use this endpoint.php as my router file?

Comment: Yes, you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use the Prestashop Webservice, that allows to add resources for modules. This solution could save some time in terms of standards and security.

This is the documentation for Prestashop Webservice, for versions 1.6 and 1.7:
https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/webservice/
https://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Using+the+PrestaShop+Web+Service

The documentation regarding module resources in Prestashop Webservice is in this link:

https://webkul.com/blog/creating-prestashop-module-webservice-api/

Comment: Add this also https://www.h-hennes.fr/blog/2018/06/25/prestashop-ajouter-un-objet-dans-lapi/